# How do I pass std::array as a template parameter with a varying number of elements in C++?

Tags: c++, parameters, std, stdarray

I'm trying to make a template function that lets me use an std::array object as a parameter with a varying number of elements.

For example:

```
#include <array>

template <class T>
void func(std::array<T,/*varying#ofelems*/> ary){...}
```

Comment: `template<class T, size_t ary>` ?

Comment: @KamilCuk Quite confusing, `ary` is the name of the array in Mot's code.

Comment: @O'Neil looks like Op edited the code after my comment. It was `void func(std::array<T, /*varying@ofeleems ary>)`.

Answer (score 6):

You just specify the number of elements inside the template parameters.

```
template<class T, size_t N>
void func(std::array<T, N> arr) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way don't be to strict:

```cpp
template <class T>
void func(const T& ary)
{
    ....
}
```

This way you will cover not only `std::array`, but also `std::vector` or other containers.

Comment: Can you show how do I instantiate this function with your example? `func<std::array>(ary);` ? What if I am passing multiple array args? Which size to put in the template?

Comment: Got it, so that's letting the compiler deduce the template parameter on its own? I'm new to C++, if you could also highlight a scenario where this might not work/could be dangerous?

Comment: If you are new to C++ then don't learn how to write templates now. This is most complex part of C++ and you can live without it for very long time. Also mastering basic o C++ is crucial to when you are learning templates.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, I would recommend following the lead of the standard algorithms and taking two templated iterators for begin and end instead.

```
template <class InputIt>
void func(InputIt begin, InputIt end) {
    ...
}
```